# How can I monitor memory usage in Perl on Solaris?

Tags: perl, solaris, memory-management

I want to monitor memory usage when running a program in perl, so that if the memory used by the current program is more than a threshold, I apply approach A, otherwise, apply approach B.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: This is most likely OS specific. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Related, close duplicate: [How can I programmatically determine my Perl program's memory usage under Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115743/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-my-perl-programs-memory-usage-under-windows). Some of the answers given work in *nix environments only.

Answer (score 3):

I found this script from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=235757:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use Proc::ProcessTable;  

sub memory_usage {  
  my $t = new Proc::ProcessTable;  
  foreach my $got ( @{$t->table} ) {  
    next if not $got->pid eq $$;  
    return $got->size;  
  }  
}  


print 'memory: '. memory_usage()/1024/1024 ."\n";
```

Comment: You should learn to format the code correctly on SO, but +1 for good effort and good result.

Comment: ROFL... looks like 3 people tried to format the code correctly at the same time :)

Comment: I did use `` to include the code, but it did not work this time. I also tried highlight some words sometimes ago using 4 spaces. did not work either. Thanks all for editing my article. Yes, definitely need to spend some time to learn how to edit in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be highly OS specific. For Linux, I was able to find the CPAN module [`Sys::Statistics::Linux`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys::Statistics::Linux), which is able to read `/proc` and get you data about your current process. On the off-chance that you're running on Solaris, there's [`Solaris::Procfs`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Solaris::Procfs). I couldn't find anything for Windows.

**Update**: Since you *are* on Solaris, you definitely want [`Solaris::Procfs`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Solaris::Procfs).

Comment: Thanks I will try both Solaris::Procfs and Proc::ProcessTable
This is a very good forum where I can learn in a quick way. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GTop`](http://p3rl.org/GTop) if you want something slightly more portable. The [`mod_perl` manual has usage examples](http://perl.apache.org/search/swish.cgi?query=gtop).