# Is there a CPAN Perl module to find total/used/free memory on a host (without running command line through a system() call)?

Tags: perl, memory, memory-management, cpan

Is there a CPAN Perl module which provides total/used/free memory (like `vmstat` does) on a host without running a command line through a `system()` call to get the info?

Ideally it should be cross-platform (Linux and Solaris) though please provide Linux or Solaris-only ones as well.

Comment: Very useful question... I asked [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115743/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-my-perl-programs-memory-usage-under-windows) a while back but was more interested in a Windows solution at the time

Comment: FYI: I found http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys::MemInfo but not certain if it uses command line calls underneath.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like [`Sys::MemInfo`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys%3a%3aMemInfo) is what I needed.

It is implemented in XS, using `<sys/sysinfo.h>` for Linux and `<sys/stat.h>` / `<sys/swap.h>` for Solaris.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Sys::Statistics::Linux](http://search.cpan.org/~bloonix/Sys-Statistics-Linux-0.60/) distrubition for linux.